# I am trying update a Column only if the Work Phone starts with 08

Tags: sql, sql-update, where-clause

```
UPDATE Contact
  SET MobilePhone = WorkPhone
    WHERE left(WorkPhone, 2) LIKE '%01%' 
      and MobilePhone = NULL and User = 992;
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Probably "why doesn't it return anything?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
UPDATE Contact
    SET MobilePhone = WorkPhone
    WHERE WorkPhone LIKE '08%' AND  -- WorkPhone starts with "08"
          MobilePhone IS NULL AND    -- Probably your real problem
          User = 992;
```

Use only `LIKE` for "starts with".  Your title says "08" so this uses that.

Your real problem is probably the `= NULL` because that will never return true, so no rows would ever be updated.

Comment: It does not work, I am trying to update the MobilePhone with the WorkPhone, where the WorkPhone starts with 08 and the MobilePhone is NULL. I am sorry if I have not explained it correctly.

Comment: @JasonMerrigan . . . That is exactly what this phone does, with the added condition on `User`.

Comment: @JasonMerrigan . . . Do you understand what `LIKE '08%'` does?

Comment: Sorry the above has worked I have removed the NULL as you suggested as it has worked, thank you !

Comment: yes, It looks a the the string where the first two Chars are 08

Answer (score 1):

You can try below - you need to add `MobilePhone is NULL` instead of `MobilePhone = NULL`

```
UPDATE Contact
  SET MobilePhone = WorkPhone
    WHERE left(WorkPhone, 2) LIKE '08%' 
      and MobilePhone is NULL and User = 992;
```